# Switch panels in a single view or redirect to other pages?

Tags: jsf-2, web, primefaces

I am programming an application (not a website) with a north panel that stays the same, a west panel for the menus and a center panel. The west panel and the center panel can change.

In terms of conception, is it better to work on a single view and switch panels or should I create several pages ?

For example :
Solution 1 : Center panel shows a car image, I select a car brand on the west panel, as a result I switch the west panel with another menu (car models of the brand) and switch the center panel with an image of the brand logo.

Solution 2 : Center panel shows a car image, I select a car brand on the west panel, as a result I redirect to another page with on the left menu the car models of the brand and in center panel an image of the brand logo.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use solution 2 with apply JSF Templating. By applying this approach, your pages are easy to extend and reuse.

This is my example which use `p:layout`, `ui:composition` and etc.

layout.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
        <title>Layout-menu</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <p:layout>
            <p:layoutUnit position="west" 
                          resizable="true" 
                          size="250" 
                          minSize="40" 
                          maxSize="400">
                <h:form>
                    <p:menu>
                        <p:submenu label="Navigations">
                            <p:menuitem value="input" 
                                        outcome="inputText" 
                                        icon="ui-icon-star"/>
                            <p:menuitem value="dropdown" 
                                        outcome="selectOneMenu" 
                                        icon="ui-icon-star"/>
                        </p:submenu>
                    </p:menu>
                </h:form>
            </p:layoutUnit>

            <p:layoutUnit position="center">
                <ui:insert name="source" />
            </p:layoutUnit>
        </p:layout>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

inputText.xhtml

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
                template="layout.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="source">
        <h:form>
            inputText
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

selectOneMenu.xhtml

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
                template="layout.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="source">
        <h:form>
            selectOneMenu
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

You can run test at the layout.xhtml page like this `http://host:port/project/layout.xhtml`

You can see more information about Templating from another site such as [JSF 2 Templating With Facelets Example](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-templating-with-facelets-example/), [Using Facelets Templates](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giqxp.html) and etc.